# The correct mechanism to build pool of resources

Tags: project-reactor

Let's assume that we have some expensive object that we can create and pool ahead of time. Let's further assume these objects can be consumed at an unknown rate and are discarded once they are used. We would like a mechanism so that we can tell the producer...start building more of these once you have less than N objects. What is the correct operator or process to achieve such a pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [Reactor pool](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-pool) project?
It is a reactive-first pooling solution from Project Reactor by [Simon Baslé](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1113486/simon-basl%C3%A9) and seems to cover your requirements pretty well.